# Changing keyboard layout between insert and normal mode

Tags: vim, windows-7

In my daily work in Vim's insert mode I use my native Croatian keyboard layout (HR) to which I'm accustomed at. In normal mode it is more practical for me to be in English keyboard layout (EN) since it has brackets [] and curved parenthesis {} and generally Vim's shortcuts make better use of it.

Is there a way to change keyboard modes automatically between modes?

Comment: As an aside, are you aware of [vi.se](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) which is dedicated to just vi and vim questions. As this doesn't specifically involve programming, it may be better suited to the other site.

Comment: @MichaelT - Quite aware. Without getting into discussion whether vim questions are ontopic here, since that one has already been beaten to death a few times, I will slowly migrate vim questions there, but until that site gets some more users, I'm leaving them here.

Answer (score 4):

Vim can use *keymap* files to translate typed keys in insert mode; it even ships with a Croatian one (`$VIMRUNTIME/keymap/croatian.vim`)! `:help mbyte-keymap` explains this well:

> When the keyboard doesn't produce the characters you want to enter in your
>   text, you can use the 'keymap' option.  This will translate one or more
>   (English) characters to another (non-English) character.  This only happens
>   when typing text, not when typing Vim commands.  This avoids having to switch
>   between two keyboard settings.

Basically, this configuration should do it (together with using an English keyboard layout in the operating system):

```
:set keymap=croatian
```

Any you use it like that:

> In Insert and Command-line mode you can use CTRL-^ to toggle between using the
>   keyboard map or not.
>   This flag is remembered for Insert mode with the 'iminsert' option.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I can't say I still understand what keymap does. Editing the croatian keymap file, I see it has something to do with encodings, but for the lives of me, together with the help topics you pointed to, I still cannot understand it. 
I'm actually using the HR keyboard layout in the operating system, as my default layout. So I'm trying for Vim to switch to EN while in Normal mode.

Comment: Please, if you could provide some further clarification.

Comment: Well, that way around, it's gonna be difficult. I would suggest you first try using Vim with EN layout, and using the provided Croatian keymap for insert mode. If that already suits you, fine.

Comment: I'm afraid that just doesn't work for me, since by being in EN mode in my OS by default, it would solve my Vim problem, but create a problem in every other application out there (from Word, Excel, to ...).

Comment: You can set up keys to quickly switch input locales. Also, I think Windows even remembers the locale used for a particular application (when switching e.g. with Alt-Tab). I'm afraid you don't have many other options; there's only the invasive `:autocmd` / `system()` solution mentioned in the comments.

Comment: What :autocmd/system() solution mentioned in the comments? I don't see anything in the comments (to this question).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought I had seen it here, but it must have been another similar question. I've added another answer; though it expands on the comment, it's unfortunately far from a complete solution, and I'm not sure it's actually feasible.

Comment: Where could I find keymap for french azerty keyboard on macos?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to change the default keyboard layout not in *insert*, but in *normal* mode (and presumably the other modes as well), you can't use the *keymap* feature. Instead, you have to use external commands to toggle the operating system's input locale (if that's possible in Windows, maybe via [how to change keyboard layout via command line cmd exe on windows xp](https://superuser.com/questions/395818/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-via-command-line-cmd-exe-on-windows-xp-7)). Sketch:

```
:autocmd InsertLeave * call system('locale-change EN')
:autocmd InsertEnter * call system('locale-change HR')
```